# How to get the number of business days between two dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have the following column in a dataframe, I would like to add a column to the end of this dataframe, where the column has the business days from today (6/24) to the previous day.

Bday() function does not seem to have this capability.

```
Date
2019-6-21
2019-6-20
2019-6-14
```

I am looking for a result that looks like following:

```
Date         Business days
2019-6-21      1
2019-6-20      2
2019-6-14      6
```

Is there an easy way to do this, other than doing individual manipulations or using datetime library

Answer (score 2):

Use [`np.busday_count`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.busday_count.html):

```
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # if needed
np.busday_count(df['Date'].dt.date, np.datetime64('today'))
# array([1, 2, 6])

df['bdays'] = np.busday_count(df['Date'].dt.date, np.datetime64('today'))
df
        Date  bdays
0 2019-06-21      1
1 2019-06-20      2
2 2019-06-14      6
```

Comment: It worked, but I got this following error: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @JeshKundem It's not an error, it's a warning. I need you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas/53954986#53954986) carefully, and then add `df = df.copy()` at the top of this code.